# Find smallest natural n>0 such that $2^n > (100 \times n)^{(100^{100})}$

Tags: numerical-methods

I am studying complexity theory and have reduced one of the exercises to the  inequality.

$$2^n > (100 \times n)^{(100^{100})}$$

Are there any numeric methods (possibly, programming libraries) that will be able to find smallest natural $n >0$ satisfying it?

It seems the answer is between $100^{101}$ and $100^{102}$.

Comment: Please use **\times** instead of * for the product sign : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lambert-W function solves the equation $ye^y=x$. Over the reals, it has two branches, one with index $-1$ mapping $(-e^{-1},0)$ to $(-\infty,-1)$ monotonically falling and the index zero branch mapping $(-e^{-1},\infty)$ to $(-1,\infty)$ monotonically increasing.

Bring the equation into the above form, esp. identify $y$.
$$
2^n>(M⋅n)^N\iff e^{\ln 2 \cdot n/N}>M⋅n\iff -\frac{\ln2⋅n}Ne^{-\frac{\ln2⋅n}N}>-\frac{\ln2}{NM}
$$
On the zero branch of the Lambert-W function we get
$$
-\frac{\ln2⋅n}N>W_0\left(-\frac{\ln2}{NM}\right)\iff n<-\frac{N}{\ln2}W_0\left(-\frac{\ln2}{NM}\right)\sim\frac1M
$$
which gives no solution.

On the other $W_{-1}$ branch we get
$$
-\frac{\ln2⋅n}N<W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln2}{NM}\right)\iff n>-\frac{N}{\ln2}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln2}{NM}\right)
$$
With $M=100$ and $N=100^{100}$ this gives
$$
n>\frac{100^{100}⋅471.64492813697046}{\ln 2}=6.804397988836388⋅100^{101}
$$
You would need a multi-precision implementation to be able to determine the exact smallest value for $n$. For instance in Magma CAS ([online](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)) the scipt

```
RR := RealField(240);
M := RR!100; N := M^M;
n := M*N;
for k in [1..240] do  n := Log(RR!2,M*n)*N; end for; n;
```

or with Newton

```
n := M*N; L2:=Log(RR!2);
for k in [1..7] do n:=n*N*(Log(M*n)-1)/(L2*n-N); n; end for;
```

gives the result

```
6804397988836388082768455850030996687989728466041200158720565632303321598433
  24376653075166587535687740823838573648080603275323232029104967581035695697
  18034366279018545983239970527758425935354868491153542.55079187667491436363
  201084068556561
```

Comment: I might actually delete my answer because I prefer this approach. Note that the exact value of the lower bound for natural number $n$ is $n\ge$`68043979888363880827684558500309966879897284660412001587205656323033215984332437665307516658753568774082383857364808060327532323202910496758103569569718034366279018545983239970527758425935354868491153543` if you want to add it to your answer.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Magma CAS, so I am curious why 240 is sufficient. But it seems the documentation guarantees that all calculations will be accurate up to 240  decimal digits. Good enough, accepting the answer.

Answer (score 5):

We can take the logarithm base $2$ both sides multiple times so that this becomes
$$n\gt100^{100}\log_2{(100n)}$$
$$100n\gt100^{101}\log_2{(100n)}$$
$$\log_2{(100n)}\gt\log_2{(100^{101}\log_2{(100n)})}$$
$$\log_2{(100n)}\gt101\log_2{(100)}+\log_2{(\log_2{(100n)})}$$
$$\log_2{(100n)}-\log_2{(\log_2{(100n)})}-101\log_2{(100)}\gt0$$
Now using the change of variable $u=\log_2{(100n)}$ we can easily solve numerically
$$u-\log_2{(u)}-101\log_2{(100)}\gt0$$
$$\implies u\gt680.439798883638808276845585003099668798973\dots$$
$$\implies100n\gt2^{680.439798883638808276845585003099668798973\dots}$$
$$\implies n\gt\frac1{100}2^{680.439798883638808276845585003099668798973\dots}$$
$$\implies n\gt10^{-2+\log_{10}(2)\times680.439798883638808276845585003099668798973\dots}$$
$$\implies n\gt10^{202.8327897075420269711393974772362736472055405050149061014\dots}$$
$$\implies n\gt100^{101.4163948537710134855696987386181368236027702525074530507\dots}$$
The smallest natural $n$ is then
$$n_{\min}=\lfloor100^{101.4163948537710134855696987386181368236027702525074530507\dots}\rfloor+1=$$

```
68043979888363880827684558500309966879897284660412001587205656323033215984332437665307516658753568774082383857364808060327532323202910496758103569569718034366279018545983239970527758425935354868491153543
```

which I was able to calculate using [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(2%5E(-1%2Fln(2)%20productlog(-1,%20-ln(2)%20*10%5E(-202)))%2F100)%2B1). Note that the constant $680.439798883638808276845585003099668798973\dots$ can be found explicitly using the Lambert-W function.

Comment: You could remove the second half by going back to the first formula for the back-substitution, $$n > n^*= 100^{100}\log_2(100n^*)=100^{100}u^*=6.8043979888...⋅100^{101}.$$

Comment: Yeah you can. I initially thought the OP wanted the answer in the form $n\gt100^k$ so I thought this was a better method. But obviously there are better ways.